# MOSS 2007 Published Site Page Status

Tags: sharepoint-2007, moss

Greetings all,

I have a question.

On my MOSS 2007 dev box, I created a new sharepoint site using the **Publishing -> Publishing Site** template.

Now, On this site, I can create pages, check them in, publish them, etc.

What I want to do is create a scope that I can do searches on.  However, one of the filters I want to apply to the scope is to ignore everything which is not published.

Does anyone out there know of a property (which I can use in a metadata property in my shared service which is in turn used in my scope) to determine if a page is in a published status, draft status, any other sort of status?

Does such a property exist?

Thanks in advance for your help.

cmb..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, when you view pages in a SharePoint site, and you're not signed in (eg your a anon user) then you will only see the last published version of that page. You won't see the version currently being edited (if it is checked out).

Now, if you want to stop users who are signed in from searching any pages which are not checked in, then have a look at filtering using the 'Approved Status' field. I'm not sure how to do this myself, but that's usually the field you filter on for stuff like views.

Comment: Hi there, 

Thanks for getting back to me.  Question: I am trying to track down this "Approved Status" to map to my created metadata property.
 Which Crawled Property do I have to add?  What Category is it in?  I looked through all the categories and can't seem to see it. I could be blind however.... :-)

Comment: I don't have access to a SharePoint system at the moment, I'm trying to remember the crawled property names by memory - not working out well :) I was hoping there would be something like ows_approvalstatus, or something like that. I don't know I'm afraid.

Comment: I believe the field is ModerationStatus as Gurdas states. I can't seem to see it find you..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the "Approval Status" field is what you're looking for.

The property you need to map to is "_ModerationStatus" within your SSP search configuration.